# Will the break codes of keyboard be sent to the keyboard buffer?

Tags: assembly, hardware

As we know, when we press a key on the keyboard, it generates a "make code" and causes INT 9 to send the make code and ASCII code to the keyboard buffer or set relevant binary bit(like ctrl, shift and alt).

Also, when we release a key on the keyboard, it generates a "break code"(sometimes `"break code" = "make code" + 80H`).

So, I wonder whether the break code is sent to the keyboard buffer and I write this code:

```
assume cs:code

code segment
    start:
    mov ax,stack
    mov ss,ax
    mov sp,64

    mov ah,10H
    int 16H
    mov ah,10H
    int 16H

    mov ah,4CH
    int 21H
code ends

end start
```

When I run this code in `Debug`, from the second `INT 16H`, I press a and also get a return value 1E61 in AX, it seems that the break code isn't in the keyboard buffer.

If so, how does computer know when I release a key(especially for shift, ctrl)? Or it doesn't need to know? When I release a key, where does the break code go?

Comment: You said it :) It's the INT 9 handler that alters the state of the keyboard buffer based on the scancode it reads. Break codes simply don't add a new character but it doesn't mean they are ignored altogether. They can be used to toggle the key up/down state. Plus, IIRC, it is the keyboard that sends repeated scancode when a key is down (not sure though).

Comment: @MargaretBloom Wait..... Maybe the break codes don't go to the buffer indeed, and computer knows when I release a key that has ASCII code by the time the repeated make codes stop. And when the make code of shift(just for example) is  detected, CPU toggle shift up; when the break code of shift detected, CPU toggle shift down. It seams somewhat reasonable.XD

Comment: I've disassembled the Bochs BIOS and can confirm that it check for the break scan code of L/R-CTRL, L/R-SHIFT, CAPS LOCK, NUM LOCK and SCROLL LOCK. Every other scancode with bit7 set is ignored.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Er..... What does "bit7 set" mean?

Comment: It is customary in the x86 world to name bits right to left (from LSb to MSb) starting from 0. So in 1010, bit0 = 0, bit1 = 1, bit2 = 0, bit3 = 1. This extends to arbitrary lengths. Not everyone follows this convention. I should have been more clear.

Comment: @MargaretBloom So, do you mean the break codes of the keys that have corresponding ASCII code are all ignored?